# Using ArrayDeque Java

Tags: java, storage, arraydeque

I'm trying to store a list of primes using java and came across ArrayDeque. I'm not sure if this is the correct occasion to use it, but since I don't know the number of primes I need the capacity to grow.

The code is designed to go through numbers 2 to 1000 and test if they are a prime or not.

I'm getting some errors. I am pretty new to this so if anybody could guide me in the right direction that would be great. Is using a Array with a large pre-set capacity a better way of doing things?

Many thanks,
Behzad

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;

public class Maths {
public static void main (String[] arg) {        

    int x = 2;
    ArrayDeque<integer> primes = new ArrayDeque<integer>(8);

    for(int count = 2; count<1000; count++) {
        if (x%count == 0) {
            System.out.println("Number is not prime"); // If it isn't a prime, it moves onto the next number.
            x = x + 1;
            count = 2;
        }

        else if (x >1000) {
            break;
        }

        else if (count == x - 1) {
            System.out.println( x + " is a prime"); //This possibility singles out prime numbers
            primes.add(x);
            x = x + 1;                              // Need to find a way to add them to memory.
            count = 2;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Searchfinished");
    System.out.println(primes);
}
}
```

Comment: java has no `integer`. The primitive is `int`, the object is `Integer`.

Comment: Also, "getting some errors" is no help to us. Please provide the errors.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "I'm getting some errors"?

Comment: `Array deques have no capacity restrictions; they grow as necessary to support usage`

Comment: Your `count` variable never gets to 1000 as you always reset it to value 2. I guess you're getting `OutOfMemoryException` because your program runs out of memory.

Comment: I think the whole implementation of finding prime numbers is not correct!

Comment: It depends on your usage. How do you intend to use it after that? How do you need the primes after having found them?
You should also check your implementation: try to loop on `x` and use `count` from 2 to `x` in each loop. Or look for other methods, this one is quite naive.

Comment: The program would go in an infinite loop, since `count` is reset to 2, only after you correct the `ArrayDeque<integer>` to `ArrayDeque<Integer>`.

Comment: @RahulBobhate The program works fine for me (after correcting the `Integer`)

Comment: Ok obviously a lot wrong with my code at the moment. I'll start fixing it up!

@David M I'm doing a projecteuler exercie where I have to find the largest prime factor of a number, so I was going to form a list of primes and then test each one and printing the largest prime factor.

Comment: @Behzad Alright. How about finding the factors first, then start with the largest ones to find out which one is prime? If you prefer your method, remember you only need to test primes up to the square root of the number.

Answer (score 3):

There's no thing in Java like `integer`. The proper one is `Integer`.

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    int x = 2;
    Deque<Integer> primes = new ArrayDeque<Integer>(8);

    for(int count = 2; count<1000; count++) {
      if (x%count == 0) {
          System.out.println("Number is not prime"); // If it isn't a prime, it moves onto the next number.
          x = x + 1;
          count = 2;
      } else if (x > 1000) {
          break;
      } else if (count == x - 1) {
          System.out.println( x + " is a prime"); //This possibility singles out prime numbers
          primes.add(x);
          x = x + 1;                              // Need to find a way to add them to memory.
          count = 2;
      }
  }
  System.out.println("Searchfinished");

  System.out.println(primes);
 }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be more correct:  Deque<Integer> primes = new ArrayDeque<>(8);  ???